# Looping angular object in bootstrap grid

Tags: angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap, angular-material, angular-bootstrap

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

i just want to display cards in my angular app as that particular grid

3 cards in  a row then in the next row

```
   <div class="container" *ngFor="let item of post">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">
          <h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
    
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
```

this is how it turned out

[image]
instead of column

it's just fetched those object data as rows
is there any way where we could loop over that grid and display data accordingly

```
Note:I have tried Angular material Grid
```

i have tried using Flexlayout still no luck with that

[image]

i just need a possible way where i can dispaly data like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that you are facing comes to the fact that you are creating the `loop` on the container div; which then creates 3 container per card instead of a single container.

```
   <div class="container" *ngFor="let item of post">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">
          <h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
    
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
```

In order to implement what you want (a container with `N` cards) you have to declare the `loop` on the card elements.

```
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm" *ngFor="let item of post">
          <h2>{{item.title}}</h2
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

That way you will have a container, then a row, and finally the list of components created from the iteration.

You can read a little here:
[Angular ngFor example](https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data#add-logic-to-loop-through-data) and here
[ngForOf Directive](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf)

Comment: yeah that's working perfectly fine 
but what if we wanna add card card to another row after 3 cards 
because with this UI structure cards are being messed within a single column 
by any chance can we make sure only 3 cards can be in  a row

Comment: I'd suggest refactoring the array to an array of subarrays of length 3. Then you would create a loop for the `row` for each subarray and then loop for each element of the subarray.

This answer can give some light: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58399994/how-to-add-row-after-every-3-columns-in-angular

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="container" >
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm" *ngFor="let item of post">
          <h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
    
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
```